# Excluir registros asociados a un cliente en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Estoy diseñando una query para obtener el conjunto de 1000 clientes potenciales de una ciudad a partir de las ventas desde un periodo hasta la fecha.

la query hace lo que pretendía desde un principio, pero mi gran inconveniente es que si el cliente compró dos veces en ese periodo me muestra dos registros y no quiero que suceda esto, solo necesito 1 registro de ese cliente.

Query

```
select top 1000  id_credito,
            valor,
            c.id_municipio,
            pt.RESULTADO as saldo,
            id_tercero_cliente,
            tercero.nombre, 
            c.fecha,
            DATEDIFF(day,c.fecha_estimada,(SELECT TOP 1 fecha_pago FROM abono
                                    WHERE id_credito = c.id_credito
                                    ORDER BY id_abono DESC))as duracion
            from credito c
            INNER JOIN tercero ON tercero.id_tercero = c.id_tercero_cliente
            CROSS APPLY AQ_ObtenerSaldoCredito_TableOnline(id_credito)pt            
            where fecha >'01-01-2018'
            and c.id_municipio = 1048
            and pt.RESULTADO = 0
            and valor > 1000000         
            and fecha_estimada >= (SELECT TOP 1 fecha_pago FROM abono
                                    WHERE id_credito = c.id_credito
                                    ORDER BY id_abono DESC)
```

he intento añadir una expresion como esta, pero no logro resultado

```
--and c.id_tercero_cliente not in (select id_tercero_cliente from credito)
```

que puedo hacer para evitar esto. He pensado en hacer la consulta directamente a la tabla clientes lo que implica reformar la query que llevo hasta el momento

Comment: Usando `distinct (id_tercero_cliente)`?

Comment: intente algo similar select distinct  top 1000... y no resulto

Comment: Cómo usaste distinct? por qué no resultó? El distinct debiste usarlo con el id_tercero_cliente, así como te lo escribí...

Comment: incluyendo el distinct luego del select y antes del top 1000, posterior a eso inverti el orden de la columna id_tercero_cliente con id_credito

Comment: http://collabedit.com/9gukw checa aqui, como lo añadi

Comment: Deberías investigar el uso de distinct. Básicamente distinct lo aplicas a una columna para que no devuelva valores duplicados. por eso es que lo escribí `distinct (id_tercero_cliente)`. Desconozco por qué lo lo pusiste antes del top 1000... tampoco entiendo por qué cambiaste de lugar la columna id_tercero_cliente, creo que no afecta dónde se encuentre.

Comment: debes tener claro que no estoy hablando de valores duplicados, son registros totalmente diferentes de un mismo cliente. Se añade antes del top porque sencillamente después de él no lo toma.

Comment: Desconozco cómo obtener el resultado que deseas sin reescribir la consulta. Te sugiero que revises cuáles columnas hacen diferente a un registro de otro, generalizándola para obtener el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Con una subquery, primero traes los primeros 1000 clientes distintos, y luego lo vuelves a unir con la query principal

```
select          top 1000
                id_credito,
                valor,
                c.id_municipio,
                pt.RESULTADO      as saldo,
                id_tercero_cliente,
                tercero.nombre,
                c.fecha,
                datediff(   day,
                            c.fecha_estimada,
                (
                    select  top 1
                            fecha_pago
                    from
                            abono
                    where
                            id_credito = c.id_credito
                    order by
                            id_abono desc
                )
                        )         as duracion
from
                credito                                        c
    inner join  tercero
        on tercero.id_tercero = c.id_tercero_cliente
    cross apply AQ_ObtenerSaldoCredito_TableOnline(id_credito) pt
where
                fecha > '01-01-2018'
                and c.id_municipio = 1048
                and pt.RESULTADO = 0
                and valor > 1000000
                and fecha_estimada >=
                (
                    select  top 1
                            fecha_pago
                    from
                            abono
                    where
                            id_credito = c.id_credito
                    order by
                            id_abono desc
                )
                and tercero.id_tercero in
                    (
                        select          top 1000
                                        id_tercero_cliente
                        from
                                        credito                                        c
                            inner join  tercero
                                on tercero.id_tercero = c.id_tercero_cliente
                            cross apply AQ_ObtenerSaldoCredito_TableOnline(id_credito) pt
                        where
                                        fecha > '01-01-2018'
                                        and c.id_municipio = 1048
                                        and pt.RESULTADO = 0
                                        and valor > 1000000
                                        and fecha_estimada >=
                                        (
                                            select  top 1
                                                    fecha_pago
                                            from
                                                    abono
                                            where
                                                    id_credito = c.id_credito
                                            order by
                                                    id_abono desc
                                        )
                        group by
                                        id_tercero_cliente
                    );
```

Comment: Con la respuesta que incorporas no puede resolver el inconveniente, puede lograrlo empleando una subconsulta en el select inicial:  de esta manera `(select top 1 nombre from tercero
     where tercero.id_tercero = c.id_tercero_cliente ) as nombre,`